# Django admin: rendering page to add new object fails only when datetime field is included in fieldset

Tags: python, django, datetime, django-admin

I've been working on a Django app to replace a spreadsheet-based sports picking game I play with some friends. I defined my Game model a while ago, but recently added a datetime field to signify the starting time of the game/match:

```
class Game(models.Model):
  home_team = models.CharField(max_length=100, default='---')
  away_team = models.CharField(max_length=100, default='---')
  spread = models.FloatField(default=0)    
  week = models.IntegerField(default=0)
  home_team_score = models.IntegerField(default=0)
  away_team_score = models.IntegerField(default=0)
  start_time = models.DateTimeField(default='2015-09-01 13:00:00')

  def has_started(self):
    if datetime.now() >= self.start_time:
        return True
    return False
  def __str__(self):
    return '%s vs. %s, week: %i' % (self.home_team, self.away_team, self.week)
```

I just noticed that when I use the Django admin functionality to add a new Game, the creation page errors out. However, if I click on an existing Game, the page displays fine, and I can edit the starting time as expected.

The error thrown is:

```
 AttributeError at /admin/app/game/add/
'str' object has no attribute 'date'
```

Some searching returned similar issues, however they were related to definining the datetime field with `auto_now` or `auto_now_add` as `True`, so the fix is to make sure it handles those fields as read-only.

This situation is different, as if I define a custom `fieldset` in admin.py, that doesn't include the time field, the creation page does not error out when I click to add a new one. For example:

```
class GameAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
  fieldsets = [
    ('League week', {'fields': ['week'], }),
    ('Teams',       {'fields': ['home_team', 'away_team'], }),
    ('Spread',      {'fields': ['spread'], }),
              ]

  list_filter = ['week']
  search_fields = ['home_team','away_team']
```

This works just fine to add a new Game, and I can go back to the default admin layout to change the default time.

I thought I might need to import date from datetime, but adding that didn't help. Is there a different way I need to define my fieldset in order to handle dates properly?

Comment: try setting `default` attribute of `start_time` to an object of `datetime.datetime` i.e. `datetime.datetime.now()` or in your case `datetime.datetime(year=2015, month=9, day=1, hours=13)`

Comment: Thank you- that works perfectly! I guess my assumption that auto parsing a string would be fine wasn't quite right. If you add that as an answer, I'll accept it ASAP.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set default attribute of `start_time` to an object of `datetime.datetime` i.e. `datetime.datetime.now()` or in your case

```
datetime.datetime(year=2015, month=9, day=1, hours=13)
```

Although it is considered good practise to use current/dynamic time as `default` by setting

```
default = datetime.datetime.now
```

or

```
default = django.utils.timezone.now
```

for timezone aware datetime (see brackets () are absent after .now), but it depends on your use case.

Comment: Noted on best practice- as you probably guessed, my current default is a placeholder, and I'll also be adding the typical created/modified fields which will both default to `now`